# VBA PowerPoint credits effect repeat

Tags: vba, powerpoint, timing

I created a textbox in VBA that has `msoAnimEffectCredits`. If I create such an animation manually, I can select several repeat settings in timing, one of them being `until next click`. I can not find any documentation on how to set this in VBA. I can set repeat to a number, such as

```
ThisEff.Timing.RepeatCount = 10
```

When I set the repeat to `until next click` manually, and then use VBA to read the value of `RepeatCount`, it displays -2147483648. But if I try to SET the value of `RepeatCount` to -2147483648 in VBA, I get an error saying `RepeatCount` cannot be negative.

Leaving it set to 10 for now (can't imagine user wanting to see the credits that long anyway)… just frustrating that after hours of googling, I couldn't find a way to duplicate this manual animation option in VBA.

Comment: @Jay_Windley had a look at this as well and support your finding. I also couldn't seem to set Slide.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(1).Timing.RepeatCount to anything other than +ve numeric seconds. It would seem that the method checks for a positive value, contrasting with the process of setting to "Until Next Click" via the PowerPoint interface (which seems to set to the -ve value in the background). I couldn't see any other method for changing. If you find a way around it ... let us know.